# How to tell hibernate tools to generate classes with the same name of my database tables?

Tags: hibernate, reverse-engineering, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-tools

I use [eclipse hibernate tools](http://hibernate.org/tools/) to generate classes from database tables. But I get classes names different from those of my database. For example I have a table that I call OT_XML in my database and the generated java class is called OtXml.

I  have a lot of columns in each table ( around 50 columns) so I can't specify by hand the name needed for each column.

Is there a way to tell hibernate tools to respect the same names of tables and attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom [ReverseEngineeringStrategy](http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2006/08/custom-reverse-engineering-strategy-in.html) to achieve that.